Simulating a noisy sine wave
I'm trying to simulate a sine wave with white Gaussian noise on my test bench. I have generated 40 values for this signal following @vipin's blog post here and integrated this module into my test bench. Then I feed this input to an ADC module. When I simulate this, I'm getting a high impedance output from the adc inputs to the ADC module. Does anyone have any idea what might be causing this?
Here are my sine wave module and test bench codes:
module sine_wave(Clk,data_out);
//declare input and output
input Clk;
output [7:0] data_out;
//declare the sine ROM - 30 registers each 8 bit wide.  
reg [7:0] sine [0:39];
//Internal signals  
integer i;  
reg [7:0] data_out; 
//Initialize the sine rom with samples. 
initial begin
    i = 0;
    sine[0] = 8'd0;
    sine[1] = 8'd12;
    sine[2] = 8'd24;
    sine[3] = 8'd35;
    sine[4] = 8'd46;
    sine[5] = 8'd55;
    sine[6] = 8'd63;
    sine[7] = 8'd70;
    sine[8] = 8'd74;
    sine[9] = 8'd77;
    sine[10] = 8'd78;
    sine[11] = 8'd77;
    sine[12] = 8'd74;
    sine[13] = 8'd70;
    sine[14] = 8'd63;
    sine[15] = 8'd55;
    sine[16] = 8'd46;
    sine[17] = 8'd35;
    sine[18] = 8'd24;
    sine[19] = 8'd12;
    sine[20] = 8'd0;
    sine[21] = 8'b11110100; //-12;
    sine[22] = 8'b11101000; //-24;
    sine[23] = 8'b11011101; //-35;
    sine[24] = 8'b11010010; //-46;
    sine[25] = 8'b11001001; //-55;
    sine[26] = 8'b11000001; //-63;
    sine[27] = 8'b10111010; //-70;
    sine[28] = 8'b10110110; //-74;
    sine[29] = 8'b10110011; //-77;
    sine[30] = 8'b10110010; //-78;
    sine[31] = 8'b10110011; //-77;
    sine[32] = 8'b10110110; //-74;
    sine[33] = 8'b10111010; //-70;
    sine[34] = 8'b11000001; //-63;
    sine[35] = 8'b11001001; //-55;
    sine[36] = 8'b11010010; //-46;
    sine[37] = 8'b11011101; //-35;
    sine[38] = 8'b11101000; //-24;
    sine[39] = 8'b11110100; //-12;
end

//At every positive edge of the clock, output a sine wave sample.
always@ (posedge(Clk))
begin
    data_out = sine[i];
    i = i+ 1;
    if(i == 40)
        i = 0;
end

endmodule

Test bench (full code is here):
// Inputs
reg Clk;

// Outputs
//reg [7:0] data_out; //I had to comment this out because the reg assignment to 
                      //data_out was giving errors

// Instantiate the Unit Under Test (UUT)
sine_wave uut (
    .Clk(Clk), 
    .data_out(data_out)
);

//Generate a clock with 10 ns clock period.
initial Clk = 0;
always #5 Clk = ~Clk;

system system_i
   (
    .adc_clk_n_i(Clk),
    .adc_clk_p_i(~Clk),
    .adc_csn_o(adc_csn_o),
    .adc_dat_a_i(data_out),
    .adc_dat_b_i(data_out),
    .adc_enc_n_o(adc_enc_n_o),
    .adc_enc_p_o(adc_enc_p_o)
   ));

Here is the adc module code (credit to Pavel Demin):
`timescale 1 ns / 1 ps

module axis_red_pitaya_adc #
 (
   parameter integer ADC_DATA_WIDTH = 14,
   parameter integer AXIS_TDATA_WIDTH = 32
 )
 (
   // System signals
   output wire                        adc_clk,

   // ADC signals
   output wire                        adc_csn,
   input  wire                        adc_clk_p,
   input  wire                        adc_clk_n,
   input  wire [ADC_DATA_WIDTH-1:0]   adc_dat_a,
   input  wire [ADC_DATA_WIDTH-1:0]   adc_dat_b,

   // Master side
   output wire                        m_axis_tvalid,
   output wire [AXIS_TDATA_WIDTH-1:0] m_axis_tdata
 );
   localparam PADDING_WIDTH = AXIS_TDATA_WIDTH/2 - ADC_DATA_WIDTH;

   reg  [ADC_DATA_WIDTH-1:0] int_dat_a_reg;
   reg  [ADC_DATA_WIDTH-1:0] int_dat_b_reg;
   wire                      int_clk0;
   wire                         int_clk;

   IBUFGDS adc_clk_inst0 (.I(adc_clk_p), .IB(adc_clk_n), .O(int_clk0));
   BUFG adc_clk_inst (.I(int_clk0), .O(int_clk));

   always @(posedge int_clk)
   begin

     int_dat_a_reg <= adc_dat_a;
     int_dat_b_reg <= adc_dat_b;
     $display("int_dat_a_reg=%d, int_dat_b_reg=%d, adc_dat_a=%d,           
 adc_dat_b=%d",int_dat_a_reg, int_dat_b_reg, adc_dat_a, adc_dat_b);
   end

   assign adc_clk = int_clk;

   assign adc_csn = 1'b1;

   assign m_axis_tvalid = 1'b1;

   assign m_axis_tdata = {
     {(PADDING_WIDTH+1){int_dat_b_reg[ADC_DATA_WIDTH-1]}},      
 ~int_dat_b_reg[ADC_DATA_WIDTH-2:0],
     {(PADDING_WIDTH+1){int_dat_a_reg[ADC_DATA_WIDTH-1]}},      
 ~int_dat_a_reg[ADC_DATA_WIDTH-2:0]};


 endmodule

Here is the output I get:
int_dat_a_reg=    Z, int_dat_b_reg=    Z, adc_dat_a=    Z, adc_dat_b=    Z
int_dat_a_reg=    Z, int_dat_b_reg=    Z, adc_dat_a=    Z, adc_dat_b=    Z
...

For reference, here are the block diagram  and the simulation waveforms (Note: led_o is the output from the adc module)

change the commented out reg [7:0] data_out in your top level test bench to wire [7:0] data_out.

Also  what is system - the diagram shows that the adc_clk_p_i signal is unconnected (Z), so clearly there is a connectivity issue in some part of the code you are enot showing us.

Thank you, that solved the problem! 'system' is the design source top module that I modified to make the test bench, you can see the full code for it in the link to the full test bench code. However, none of the simulations I ran before had any non-Z values for the input ports, but would show up on the output ports so I just assumed that that's how simulations work. Is that not the case?
